# Using grepl with variable

Tags: r

I have a large data frame and want to select certain columns.

Is it possible to select strings and numeric values of the colum names with a short command?
In python it would be 'b'+str(j). I tried as.characater(j), but it did not help.

```
a=c(1:4)
ab1=c(1,1,1,1)
ab2=c(2,1,1,1)
ab3=c(3,1,1,1)
dat <- data.frame(a,ab1,ab2,ab3)
for (j in c(1:3)) {
  new_dat <- dat[grepl('b'&j), names(dat)] #this does not work: Just to indicate what i want
    #do something
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your code. The loop `for (j in 3)` makes no sense, as `j` will only be `3`. `grepl('b'&j)` is not valid R code (you should take a look at `?grepl`).Can you please edit your question to include your expected output based on the sample data you give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
for (j in seq_along(dat)) {
        new_dat <- dat[,grepl(paste0('b',as.numeric(j)), names(dat)), drop=FALSE]

}
```

Comment: The loop `for (j in 3)` makes no sense as `j` will always and only be `3`.

Comment: @MauritsEvers I did not notice that. I think OP asked for normal for loop "I hope so", with one problem of passing the iterator to `grepl` as valid argument

Comment: Yeah I'm not really sure (either) what OP is trying to do hence my comment above. OP should clarify.

Comment: Thanks. Paste is a nice solution: dat[grepl(paste0('b',j), names(dat))]